# Full url with schema, domain and port

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

How do assemble (using Zend Routes) the full url with schema, domain and port, not just a root-based path?

Sample use case: we need to specify full url in the emails sent to the clients.

AFAIK there is no any built-in solution but what is a best practice in this case and/or what do you specifically use in such cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of `ServerUrl` and `Url` view helpers, eg

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->serverUrl($this->url(array(
    'url' => 'params'), 'route', $reset, $encode)) ?>">My Link</a>
```

Comment: @zerkms Doco on *all* the helpers is scarce. Sometimes it's good to have a browse through [Zend/View/Helper](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/View/Helper/) and [Zend/Controller/Action/Helper](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/)

Comment: yep. When you pointed me the first thing I've done is dived into the sources ;-)

Comment: That helper is very helpful !